# Adding to existing Firebase integer

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

Is it possible to add to an existing integer stored in firebase. I am building an application that keeps track of a users word count by storing a key in their `userId` firebase key called `wordCount:`. I'm able to successfully `update` that key when the user clicks a button called "marked as read" but unfortunately it just replaces the integer instead of adding to it. Is it possible to get it to add to the value of the key `wordCount:` rather than replacing it.

Here is the code inside one of my `controllers`. Side note, `angularAuth.getAuth` just checks to see if the user is logged in or not

```
this.markedAsRead = function(wordCount){
if(angularAuth.getAuth){
  var userBase = new Firebase('https://readyread.firebaseio.com/users/'+angularAuth.getAuth.uid)
  userBase.update({
    wordsRead: wordCount
  })
}else{
  console.log('please log in to use this feature')
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it thanks to an idea of @manube

```
this.markedAsRead = function(words){
var userBase = $firebaseObject(new Firebase('https://readyread.firebaseio.com/users/'+angularAuth.getAuth.uid))
var users = new Firebase('https://readyread.firebaseio.com/users/'+angularAuth.getAuth.uid)
userBase.$loaded().then(function(data){
  self.count = data.wordsRead
  users.update({
    wordsRead: self.count+words
  })
})}
```

Comment: Instead of using update, you might want to have a look at using transaction for this. I don't think AngularFire provides a wrapper for transaction, but you can just use it directly on the ref: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html